# Ranking crashes with Where Clause

Tags: mysql, crash, rank

I have a dataset have duplicated records and I'm doing a rank (As num) to dedup. It was fine while I group it and see how bad is the duplication. but where I run a query to obtain rank=1 (where rank=1), the query takes too long and crash.

Can anyone give me some insight?

```
Select num, count(*)
FROM
(SELECT
 @rank :=case   
WHEN concat_ws(':', @Agent, @calltime) = concat_ws(':', Agent_Name, CallStart) 
Then @rank + 1
ELSE 1
END AS num, 
@calltime:=CallStart AS Callstart, @Agent := Agent_Name As AgentName        
FROM granular 
ORDER BY  Callstart, AgentName
) clean
Group by num;
```

Output:

```
--------------
Num | Count(*)
--------------    
   1|   302419
   2|     7259
   3|      471
   4|       43
   5|        2
```

obtain a table only rank=1 and it crashs/take too long:

```
Select *
FROM
(SELECT
 @rank :=case   
WHEN concat_ws(':', @Agent, @calltime) = concat_ws(':', Agent_Name, CallStart) 
Then @rank + 1
ELSE 1
END AS num, 
@calltime:=CallStart AS Callstart, @Agent := Agent_Name As AgentName        
FROM granular 
ORDER BY  Callstart, AgentName
) clean
WHERE num=1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot depend on variable assignments that happen in two different expressions.  The right way to calculate the rank is to combine all variable expressions into a single expression.  I would write the expression as:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM (SELECT g.*,
             (@rn := if(@at = concat_ws(':', Agent_name, CallStart), @rn + 1,
                        if(@at := concat_ws(':', Agent_name, CallStart), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM granular g CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @at := '') params
      ORDER BY  Callstart, AgentName
     ) g
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Perhaps this will fix your problem.

Comment: Using concat_ws instead of two assignments sound more efficient but it's still the same. It just keep running and not giving a result.

Comment: @Toby . . . It's not about efficiency; it is about accuracy.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. I'm new to SQL, correct me if I'm wrong. I think it's more efficient if the query only need to check on one assignment. I agree that it improves accuracy.
 - 
One thing that I'm confused is I'm able to do a count after grouping it. How come there is a problem to present data with condition rank=1. 
 - 
It's still not working. is there any way to work around? I'm thinking instead doing a query, may be I can add a column for ranking and delete any rank>1.

Comment: @Toby . . . MySQL documentation explicitly states that the order of evaluation of `SELECT` statements is arbitrary.  Hence, when you assign variables in multiple expressions, you don't know which is going to be assigned first:  "As a general rule . . . you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement." (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Sorry I did not try your code at first and I just plug the concat into my query. It actually helps.

I kinda understand why there is a second `if` statement because we need to put a non-duplicated concat into variable @at. It's kind of weird to me since we don't really need an `if` statement and it returns `1` no matter true or false.